# Why does carrierwave save a copy of the entire model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

I have been using CarrierWave with AWS forever without issue, however in my latest project I simply cannot get it work.  The file uploads to AWS without any issue, however instead of saving the file location in the DB table, it store a copy of the entire model.  I when the page loads, I get an error because rails cannot figure out what to do with the data stored in the table
Check out below.. directly from rails console where `profile_picture` is the field using mounted to CarrierWave.

It seeme like the entire object is being saved instead of a generated URL.  Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

```
dog = Dog.first
=> #<Dog id: 2, user_id: nil, name: "Lentil", profile_picture: "971935_556519314400437_65392555_n.jpg", breed_id: 2, 
color: "fawn with black mask", age: 1, gender: "m", created_at: "2013-08-03 17:57:00", updated_at: "2013-08-03 18:12:33">

dog.profile_picture
=> #<ImageUploader:0x007f83388b70f0 @model=#<Dog id: 2, user_id: nil, name: "Lentil", profile_picture: "971935_556519314400437_65392555_n.jpg", breed_id: 2, color: "fawn with black mask", age: 1, gender: "m", created_at: "2013-08-03 17:57:00", updated_at: "2013-08-03 18:12:33">, @mounted_as=:profile_picture, @storage=#
<CarrierWave::Storage::Fog:0x007f83388b6b50 @uploader=#<ImageUploader:0x007f83388b70f0 ...>, @connection=#<Fog::Storage::AWS::Real:0x007f8336d5e3d0 @aws_access_key_id="xxx", @aws_secret_access_key="xxx", @hmac=#<Fog::HMAC:0x007f8336d5e100 @key="xxx", @digest=#<OpenSSL::Digest::Digest: xxx>, @signer=#<Proc:0x007f8336d5ddb8@/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/fog-0.9.0/lib/fog/core/hmac.rb:22 
(lambda)>>, @endpoint=nil, @host="s3.amazonaws.com", @path="/", @port=443, @scheme="https", @connection=#<Fog::Connection:0x007f8336d5db10 @excon=#<Excon::Connection:0x007f8336d5d8b8 @connection={:headers=>{}, :host=>"s3.amazonaws.com", :mock=>nil, :path=>"/", :port=>"443", :query=>nil, :scheme=>"https"}, @socket_key="s3.amazonaws.com:443">, @persistent=true>>>, @file=#<CarrierWave::Storage::Fog::File:0x007f83388b6510 @uploader=#<ImageUploader:0x007f83388b70f0 
...>, @base=#<CarrierWave::Storage::Fog:0x007f83388b6b50 @uploader=#<ImageUploader:0x007f83388b70f0 ...>, @connection=#<Fog::Storage::AWS::Real:0x007f8336d5e3d0 @aws_access_key_id="xxx", @aws_secret_access_key="xxx", @hmac=#<Fog::HMAC:0x007f8336d5e100 @key="xxx", @digest=#<OpenSSL::Digest::Digest: xxx>, @signer=#<Proc:0x007f8336d5ddb8@/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/fog-0.9.0/lib/fog/core/hmac.rb:22 
(lambda)>>, @endpoint=nil, @host="s3.amazonaws.com", @path="/", @port=443, @scheme="https", @connection=#<Fog::Connection:0x007f8336d5db10 @excon=#<Excon::Connection:0x007f8336d5d8b8 @connection={:headers=>{}, :host=>"s3.amazonaws.com", :mock=>nil, :path=>"/", :port=>"443", :query=>nil, :scheme=>"https"}, @socket_key="s3.amazonaws.com:443">, @persistent=true>>>, @path="uploads/dog/profile_picture/2/971935_556519314400437_65392555_n.jpg">, @versions={}>
```

Comment: also...I put an 'xxx' where my AWS key and password are.. they are not 'xxx' on my machine..thanks

Comment: Can you select directly from the database and show the actual data stored?

Comment: sure.. the raw data is `971011_588387701213598_486895615_n.jpg`.  Query was `SELECT * FROM dogs WHERE name='Lentil';  `It appears that the Fog gem is not properly prepending the file name with the URL path.. I have tried multiple configuration variations to no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem with the gem.. after a reinstall, everything worked as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Carrierwave overrides the getter when it mounts, so when you call `profile_picture`, it will return an instance of the uploader instead of the file URL. In the actual database, only the file URL is stored.

There are many different methods you can call on an uploader. The most common is `url`. You should read the Carrierwave documentation on Github before using the gem to avoid further confusion.

Comment: I have already read the documentation.. calling `url` provides the same data, and therefore throws an error.

Comment: can let us know what error on `url` method you are getting but let me tell you, your assumption that it storing the whole record is untrue ,reason you already checked it against the database and @LoganSerman is right it because the overridden method that carrierwave defines is the reason you are seeing that object on `dog.profile_picture`